# fopen(/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-normal_c47afe5539ba1b2094563d54dce2def7.ufm): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

**When generating my PDF with custom fonts and trying to stream like this:**

`$pdf = PDF::loadView( '/pdfs/invoice',$data); return $pdf->stream();`

local environment everything works fine. I can generate the pdf also.

production environment I am getting the error which written on the title.

And I have saved my Font files within storage/fonts and I have added 'storage/fonts' to writable_dirs within deploy.php.

I cannot set permission for every release within vendor files AND also I do not understand why the Font Caching is processed there. It should be done within my storage/fonts, since in config/dompdf.php there.

Comment: Make sure so the `vendor` directory and all subfolders has the correct permissions on the server.

Comment: It will work after changing the permission. But I cannot set permission for every release within vendor files

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. You install the packages right? If the permission somehow is incorrect, then probably you are doing something wrong when installting them. For instance running `composer install` as root something similar. Who owns the folder/files that you are not able to read?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf/issues/540

Comment: so what was the solution?

Answer (score 4):

Change vender permissions

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data website/vendor/
```

Comment: great solution, work for me

Comment: `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  vendor/dompdf/dompdf/lib/fonts` also works.